# Orthogonal Matrices and Change of Basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

2Orthogonal Matrices and Change of Basis
Let  be an ordered basis for the vector space . Recall that the coordinate matrix of a vector  in  is the column vector

If  is another basis for , then the transition matrix  from  to  changes a coordinate matrix relative to  into a coordinate matrix relative to ,

The question you will explore now is whether there are transition matrices  that preserve the length of the coordinate matrix—that is, given , does ?

For example, consider the transition matrix from Example 5 in Section 4.7,

relative to the bases for ,

and

If , then  and . (Verify this.) So, using the Euclidean norm for ,

You will see in this project that if the transition matrix  is orthogonal, then the norm of the coordinate vector will remain unchanged. You may recall working with orthogonal matrices in Section 3.3 (Exercises 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, and 82) and Section 5.3 (Exercise 65).

Definition of Orthogonal Matrix
The square matrix  is orthogonal when it is invertible and .

Show that the matrix  defined previously is not orthogonal.

Show that for any real number , the matrix

is orthogonal.

Show that a matrix is orthogonal if and only if its columns are pairwise orthonormal.

Prove that the inverse of an orthogonal matrix is orthogonal.

Is the sum of orthogonal matrices orthogonal? Is the product of orthogonal matrices orthogonal? Illustrate your answers with appropriate examples.

Prove that if  is an  orthogonal matrix, then  for all vectors  in .

Verify the result of part 6 using the bases  and .

See image:
[Orthogonal Matrices and Change of Basis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsa5Z.png)